# Problem with infinite series sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate the infinite sum of the series

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(i-1)^2}{n^3}. $$ 
Computing it with WolframAlpha results in $$\frac{2n^2-3n+1}{6n^2}.$$

I'm trying to solve it by considering it as an arithmetic series and using the formula for the nth $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2},$$ but I can't reach the correct result.

Any clue, bibliography, anything?

**EDITED**

Following the instructions of avz2611: 
$$\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)^2=\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}=\frac{n^2-2n+1}{2n^2}$$
with $a_1=0$ and $a_n=(n-1)^2$.

Comment: It's a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\0^2+1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^2=\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)(2(n-1)+1)}{6}=\\\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}$$so  $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(i-1)^2}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)^2=\\\frac{\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}}{n^3}=\\\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6n^2}$$

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you and thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

hint: you can take $n^2$ out of the summation , and the summation left will be nothing but that of consecutive squares

Comment: I've followed your hint avz2611 and MathNoob... why I'm getting it wrong again?

Comment: @MarcC You have the wrong summation formula. $$\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)^2\neq \frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Factor out a $\frac 1{n^3}$  out of the summation. Then shift the indicies and use the summation formula for $\sum i^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you factor out the $n^3$ term, you need to find the sum of $(i - 1)^2$ as people have indicated.

Here is a proof of the sum of $i^2$. We know

$$i^3 - (i - 1)^3 = 3i^2 - 3i + 1.$$

Now, notice that

$$(i^3 + (i - 1)^3 + \ldots + 1) - ((i - 1)^3 + (i - 2)^3 + \ldots + 0) = i^3$$
and
$$\sum (3i^2 - 3i + 1) = i^3 \iff \sum i^2 = \frac{i^3 + 3\sum i - \sum 1}{3}.$$

You should be able to fill in the gaps from there.